# Making A Math Equation

Tags: objective-c

I am teaching myself Objective - C and I tried out some code to do a math equation. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    - (IBAction)mathEquation:(id)sender {
        int a = 6;
        int b = 2;
        self.showAnswer.text =  int a + int b;
    }
```

Can someone please rewrite to code the correct way and post it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int result = a + b;
self.showAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
```

In Objective-C, you can't just assign a number to a string, it won't work. As you see in my code, you need to convert from a numerical value into a string. The method `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` lets you do that, and what kind of number(s) you want to include in the string. E.g. the format expression `%d` is for an integer value.

Also, once you declared your variables (`int a`, etc.), you don't need to declare them again, you'll get an error.

**I would strongly advice reading up on the basic syntax of Objective-C.**

Comment: forgot to check it. thank you!